# My D3.js code is not showing seconds in the time axis?

Tags: d3.js

I am going to draw a line chart using d3.js. I am plotting time in the x axis and speed in the y axis of different vehicle ids. But one thing I am not getting seconds from my data. the code is rounding seconds to minute. So I am getting wrong chart. I am trying to draw something like http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955.

Here is my code

```
    var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);
var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom").ticks(d3.time.minutes,5).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
.interpolate("basis")
.x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.speed); });

/* var points = popchart.selectAll(".point")
.data(data)
.enter().append("svg:circle")
.attr("stroke", "black")
.attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i) })
.attr("cx", function(d, i) { return x(d.time) })
.attr("cy", function(d, i) { return y(d.speed) })
.attr("r", function(d, i) { return 3 }); */

color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "time"; }));

var ids = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {time: d.time, speed: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });

x.domain([d3.min(data,function(d){return d.time}),d3.max(data,function(d){return d.time})]);

y.domain([
  d3.min(ids, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.speed; }); }),
  d3.max(ids, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.speed; }); })
]);

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis)
.append("text")
.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
.attr("y", 6)
.attr("dy", ".71em")
.style("text-anchor", "end")
.text("Speed (mph)");

var id = svg.selectAll(".id")
.data(ids)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "id");

id.append("path")
.attr("class", "line")
.attr("d", function(d) {return line(d.values); })
.style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

id.append("text")
.datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.time) + "," + y(d.value.speed) + ")"; })
.attr("x", 3)
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

Though I am picking time in %H:%M:%S format the second is not coming in the chart. Why is this happening?

Comment: Works for me http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/2f0286b6c19a4f167b99

Comment: So I changed the time format. It shows the %S part. But it shows 0 always

Comment: Yes. The generated ticks are "nice" values that won't have non-zero seconds unless the range is just a few minutes, and you're telling D3 to make ticks every 5 (full) minutes. If you want ticks at specific positions, set them using `.tickValues()`.

Comment: if I have two different points at 10.23.20 and 10.23.40 will they the be aligned vertically at 10.23.00? Because iam facing this problem and instead of getting a line chart I am getting some messy loops

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/8vLRdKDOiDqdZZosfUa8?p=preview See this plunker. I have place my data and its not working

Comment: Can you see my problem?

Comment: The code at all doesn't work for my data. I astonish :(

Comment: Your plnkr doesn't work for me. I get lots of errors.

Comment: See my answer it will solve your problem i hope. Otherwise you are making mistake in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting loop is only one, Your data is not sorted according to time values as i am suspecting.In Your code you add the following for sorting the data according to time. And use this sorted data to draw the line chart.
Here is the code

```
data=data.sort(function(a, b) {
                return d3.ascending(a.time,b.time);
            });
```

Then pass this sorted data to draw the line chart. You are done

Comment: That amazingly solved my problem. What's the reason of being unsorted? I just did crossfilter on the data once. The data in my tsv file are sorted but why they are loosing sorting order

Answer (score 1):

I forked your plunker, it seems as though some of the tabs in your tsv were actually spaces. 
This was, for starters, causing massive problems in your plunk, 
so for testing I've changed it to a csv, and moved your script into script.js so that it's a little more testable. 
I'll try to have another look soon, but this should make it easier for others to debug also. Let us know if this is more like what you wanted
Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/bxncPdugtRTaWTdztraC?p=preview

`d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    ...
}`